# Allow others to share my file/folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, permissions, google-drive-sharing

I have shared a folder in my Google Drive with several contacts.

**Can I grant permission to some of them, for them to be able to share with others?**
(Sort of making them admins of the folders).

This is what I see when I click on any of the members of the target directory.
I don't seem to find any way of approaching the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can I grant permission to some of them, for them to be able to share with others?

Yes you can.

**Case A**
*(You have already granted with rights)*

In this case what **they should** do is:
Pick the files they want to share and right-click on them.
From the pop-up choose `Share` and in the new pop-up choose/type the emails they want to share with.

**Depending on the rights you have granted to them**, they will now see

If they were granted just view rights

[image]

If they have editing rights they will see the following screen instead.

[image]

---

**Case B**

If **you** want to grand rights to some of your contacts for some folders/files.

**Step 1.**
Pick the files/folders you want to share and right click on them

[image]

**Step 2.**
Select `Share` from the pop-up menu

[image]

**Step 3.**

Click on `Share with people and groups`

**Step 4.**
Place your cursor in the `Add people and groups` box. Your contacts will appear as a dropdown list.
Pick the ones you want or type them and grand them with desired rights.

**Step 5.**
Share. Enjoy.

*(Keep in mind that the 3 offered options are `Edit`, `View` and `Comment`)*

Answer (score 0):

The setting to allow editors to share files applies to all editors. It's not possible to allow to do this to only few of them.

NOTE: Team Drives have more options but they apply at Team Drive level, not at folder level.

Comment: I don't even see a setting that allows others to share, even if monolithic for all members. Could you point me to that?
Please see updated OP.

Comment: I saw it in marikamitsos' answer.